# Access Parameter Query will not return > Date

Tags: date, ms-access

I have an Access query with linked to a SQL server tables.  I am trying to run a parameter query with > for APPT_End_Date and it does not work.  The field is a date/time and I even tried reformmating.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT SNAP.GHRS_IN_EMPL_ID_NO, SNAP.EMP_LAST_NAME, SNAP.EMP_FIRST_NAME, SNAP.FACILITY_CODE, Format([Action_EFF_Date],"mm/dd/yyyy") AS [Termination Date], STAT.PACT_CD, STAT.PART_LONG_DESC
FROM dbo_HR_SNAP_SNAPSHOT_EMPLOYEE AS SNAP LEFT JOIN dbo_HR_SUM_EMP_STATISTICS AS STAT ON (SNAP.GHRS_IN_EMPL_ID_NO = STAT.GHRS_IN_EMPL_ID_NO) AND (SNAP.TITL_CD = STAT.TITL_CD) AND (SNAP.APPT_ID = STAT.APPT_ID)
WHERE (((SNAP.FACILITY_CODE)="005") AND ((Format([Action_EFF_Date],"mm/dd/yyyy"))>1/1/2022) AND ((STAT.PACT_CD)='TRMAG') AND ((STAT.PART_LONG_DESC)<>'')) OR (((STAT.PACT_CD)='RETIR')) OR (((STAT.PACT_CD)='RESST')) OR (((STAT.PACT_CD)='RESAG')) OR (((STAT.PACT_CD)='OTERM')) OR (((STAT.PACT_CD)='DISM')) OR (((STAT.PACT_CD)='CTERM'))
ORDER BY SNAP.GHRS_IN_EMPL_ID_NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
.. AND ([Action_EFF_Date] > #1/1/2022#) AND ..
```